# How to calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{\alpha \to -1}\left(2\Gamma(-\alpha-1)+\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha + 1}{2}\right) \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, gamma-function

How can I compute the following limit?
$$\displaystyle \lim_{\alpha \to -1}\left(2\Gamma(-\alpha-1)+\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha + 1}{2}\right) \right)$$

The answer appears to be about -1.73

I would be really happy if someone could help me.

Answer (score 5):

Set $x=\alpha+1$ and recall that for small values of $x$ we have $\Gamma(x) = 1/x - \gamma + O(x) $, to get $$ \lim_{x\to0} 2\Gamma(-x)+ \Gamma(x/2)=\lim_{x\to0} - 2/x -2\gamma + 2/x -\gamma = -3\gamma, $$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: thank so much.  One question what is $O(x)$

Comment: @Xision: You're very welcome! That's called [Big O notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: @Xision: Please make sure to accept the answer with the approach you liked the most. :)

Comment: why a missing $O(x)$ .i don't understant. i have $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}2\Gamma(-x)+\Gamma(\frac{x}{2}) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-2}{x}-2\gamma+2O(-x)+\frac{2}{x}-\gamma+O(\frac{x}{2})$$

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [expansion](http://www.ge.infn.it/~bonvini/math/Marco_Bonvini__Gamma_function.pdf) of $\Gamma(z)$ around one of its poles:

$$
\Gamma(z-n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left(\frac{1}{z}+\psi(n+1)+\mathcal{O}(z)\right)
$$

where $\psi(z):=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$

We obtain:

$$
\underbrace{\left(\frac{2}{x+1}-\gamma\right)}_{\lim_{x\rightarrow -1}\Gamma(\frac{x+1}{2})}+\underbrace{\left(-\frac{2}{x+1}-2\gamma\right)}_{\lim_{x\rightarrow -1}2\Gamma(-x-1)}=-3\gamma\approx-1.73165
$$

Where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and we used special values of the digamma function given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

Comment: The terms $\mathcal{O}(x-1)$ will not contribute in this limit so i just didn,t wrote them down... :)

Comment: what the terms $O(x-1)$ is come from ? Could you please explain to me... :)

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? are you familiar with $\mathcal{O}$ notation?